# RSpec be_equal not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing some rspec examples for a plain old ruby class in my rails project and I am facing the following problem.
I have this constructor:

```
    class Server
        def initialize(host='localhost',options={:port => 443, :password => '', :vpncmd_bin_path => '/usr/local/bin/vpncmd', :timeout => 5})
            @host = host
            @port = options[:port].present? ? options[:port] : 443
            @password = options[:password].present? ? options[:password] : ''
            @vpncmd_bin_path = options[:vpncmd_bin_path].present? ? options[:vpncmd_bin_path] : '/usr/local/bin/vpncmd'
            @timeout = options[:timeout].present? ? options[:timeout] : 5
            @hubs = {}
            @hub_cache_dirty = true
            @hub_password_cache = {}
        end
        ...
    end
```

This test example:

```
  it "should have a default constructor that takes no argument" do
    s = SoftEther::Server.new()
    expect(s.host).to be_equal('localhost')
    expect(s.port).to be_equal('443')
    expect(s.timeout).to be_equal(5)
    expect(s.vpncmd_bin_path).to be_equal('/usr/local/bin/vpncmd')
    expect(s.password).to be_equal('')
  end
```

And rspec gives me the following result with Rails 4.2.6, jruby-9.0.5.0 and 3.4.4:

```
  1) SoftEtherSever should have a default constructor that takes no argument
     Failure/Error: expect(s.host).to be_equal('localhost')
       expected `"localhost".equal?("localhost")` to return true, got false
     # ./spec/poro/softether_spec.rb:19:in `block in (root)'
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`equal?` checks whether two instances are the same. But it returns false when two strings contains the same value but refers to different objects:

```
"foo".equals?("foo")
# => false
```

What you should really use is `eq()`

```
expect(s.host).to eq('localhost')
```

Comment: All green! Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an edge case to Simone's answer:

If you were to freeze the strings in question, you would get the result you expected:

```
irb(main):001:0> 'test'.equal? 'test'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> 'test'.freeze.equal? 'test'.freeze
=> true
```

In Ruby 2.3, this can be done by adding

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

to the top of the Ruby file.

With that said, Simone is right. You should use the `eq` matcher unless you truly want to test that you are using the same exact object instance. Then using `equal` is in order.